# Can I use the same enum in 2 different classes in C#?

Tags: c#, enums, uml

I have two classes: `Machine` and `Production`. I want to have an `enum MachineType` to use that in both classes.

If the `Production`'s `MachineType` does not correspond to the one in the `Machine` class then the `Production` cannot be completed.

My question is is it okay to connect one enum to both classes?
Or do i have to create different enums?
And how to display this on UML?

Comment: What makes you think you cannot or should not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that without problem. You denote it by drawing a dependency (dashed line, open arrow) towards the enum from any class which uses it. The enum itself appears in the attributes as typed with the enum.

[image]